# C++ primer 5th edition: Chapter 19 Controlling memory alocation

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, delete-operator

Hello on C++ primer chapter 19: Controlling memory allocation:

> The operator new and operator delete Interface
> The library defines eight overloaded versions of operator new and delete functions. The first four support the versions of new that can throw a bad_alloc exception. The next four support nonthrowing versions of new:
>
> ```
> // these versions might throw an exception
>
> void *operator new(size_t); // allocate an object
> void *operator new[](size_t); // allocate an array
> void *operator delete(void*) noexcept; // free an object
> void *operator delete[](void*) noexcept; // free an array
>
> // versions that promise not to throw; see § 12.1.2 (p. 460)
>
> void *operator new(size_t, nothrow_t&) noexcept;
> void *operator new[](size_t, nothrow_t&) noexcept;
> void *operator delete(void*, nothrow_t&) noexcept;
> void *operator delete[](void*, nothrow_t&) noexcept;
> ```

So "The first four support the versions of new that can throw a bad_alloc
exception. The next four support nonthrowing versions of new"? Where are those "first four versions of `new` that might throw?"? Can someone explain? Thank you!

Comment: You misread the quote, it's talking about the two groups of four functions each, not four overloads of `new`. And the quote ""first four versions of new that might throw" is not taken from the actual text, and is wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Please explain more. I am so confused about it.

Comment: The quote ""first four versions of new that might throw" is something you made up, it's not actually from the book. The quote from the book is "[t]he first four support the versions of new that can throw". The "first four" references **the first group** of four functions, `new` *and* `delete`, used for allocations that can throw an exception.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Ah! right! I get it now thank you so much.